# tf eula not getting any output TFVC, TEE-CLC and IntelliJ IDEA on Windows machine

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, tfvc

I have installed TFS 2018, TFVC plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and Command Line Client TEE-CLC-14.134.0.

I am not getting any king of output while entering the command `tf eula`, hence I am not able to create Repository for version control.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue or any workaround to accept the license.

PS Output:

```
PS C:\TEE-CLC-14.134.0> tf
PS C:\TEE-CLC-14.134.0> tf eula
PS C:\TEE-CLC-14.134.0>
```

Command Prompt Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are running command `tf eula` in PowerShell.

Just try to run the command in windows command line: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>  - >  `cmd`, it works for me.

---

**UPDATE:**

Just try to run `tf eula -accept`, then check if the tf command works now.

If that still not work, just try to re-download the TEE-CLC-14.134.0, then check it again.

[image]

Comment: @RajendraPurant Just try to run `tf eula -accept`, then check if the tf command works now.

Comment: @RajendraPurant Have you resolved the issue? any update?